# Android , Could I change NumberPicker to CharPicker {A+,A,B+,B.C+,C,D+,D,F}

Tags: java, android, loops

this is my code

```
np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.picker);
np.setMaxValue(9);
np.setValue(5);
np.setMinValue(1);
```

Could picker view Char ?
number = View

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `NumberPicker#setDisplayedValues()`, the `setMinValue` and `setMaxValue` correspond to the array indexing:

```
NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.picker);
np.setMinValue(0);
np.setMaxValue(8);
np.setDisplayedValues(new String[] { "A+", "A", "B+", "B", "C+", "C", "D+", "D", "F"});
```